# Run a command with C-c C-c for a specific major mode

Tags: shell-command

I have a file with a `.md` extension, and I want to run a command to interpret/parse a file when `markdown-mode` is active with a `C-c C-c` key combination, for example. I want to run this shell command:

```
aglio -i foo.md -o foo.html
```

Where`foo.md` is the file name of the current buffer and `foo.html` is this name with replaced extension (to `html`). How can I do this in Emacs?

Comment: `C-c C-c` make different things into different major modes, in `org-mode` it have very much location-specific commands.  But you could bind this on any key you want.  But into `markdown-mode` the `C-c C-c` is the prefix key, so you'd better don't rebind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running shell command could be done with `(shell-command COMMAND)`.  Then we need to make string for executing command.  We'll concatenate it from sections with `(concat ...)`.  We have 5 sections of the command:

```
(concat "aglio -i "                                    ;; 1
        (buffer-file-name)                             ;; 2
        " -o "                                         ;; 3
        (file-name-sans-extension (buffer-file-name))  ;; 4
        ".html")                                       ;; 5
```

So, if the buffer file name is `foo.md`, then result of this script will be

```
aglio -i foo.md -o foo.html
```

We could make it function, like next:

```
(defun aglio-current-file ()
  "Execute aglio shell command on current file"
  (interactive)
  (shell-command
    (concat "aglio -i " (buffer-file-name)
     " -o " (file-name-sans-extension (buffer-file-name)) ".html")))
```

We could define key for `markdown-mode-map` with next code

```
(eval-after-load 'markdown-mode
  '(define-key markdown-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c s")
    'aglio-current-file))
```

I use `C-c C-c s` instead of `C-c C-c` cause [this version](https://github.com/jrblevin/markdown-mode) of the markdown package from `melpa` uses `C-c C-c` as prefix for buffer-wide commands.